# View Results of Simple Query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to copy an Azure database for a backup using the MSDN examples.  I can do the copy but being an SQL query novice I can't figure out how to check copy status per "SELECT name, user_access_desc, is_read_only, state_desc, recovery_model_desc
FROM sys.databases;" example provided.  I can run the query but don't know how to get the results to check.  Looking at examples I see that the query returns a result set.  My question is where and how can I look at this set.  Sorry that this is so basic but I need help.

Comment: How are you running the queries such that you can't see the results?

Comment: In a vb.net application.

Comment: @user1626137 when you say resultset, do you mean dataset? As in a populated dataset? In that case you simply need to loop through the datatables the set contains, that has the info youre looking for.

Comment: No.  If I run the query above where do I find the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some VB.NET code to show you the way:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("<Your Azure Connection String>")
    Using command As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        conn.Open()

        command.CommandText = "SELECT name, user_access_desc, is_read_only, state_desc, recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases"
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, UserAcess: {1}, Is_Readonly: {2}, State: {3}, recovery: {4}", _
                                  reader("name").ToString().Trim(), _
                                  reader("user_access_desc").ToString().Trim(), _
                                  reader("is_read_only").ToString().Trim(), _
                                  reader("state_desc").ToString().Trim(), _
                                  reader("recovery_model_desc").ToString().Trim())
            End While
        End Using


        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have SQL Server Management Studio installed, it's as simple as connecting to the Azure instance and running the query (assuming your IP is in the firewall rules).

[image]

Otherwise, use the web interface to run the query

https://YourServerHere.database.windows.net/?langid=en-us

Log in here. Do not specify a database
[image]

Select a database
[image]

Run query
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I should have said that I'm doing this in vb.net code.